# Помогите сделать простой слайдер с переписью массива?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

https://codepen.io/predaytor/pen/VgaZXJ

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #292929;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.one {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.two {
  background-color: #A5B1F1;
}

.three {
  background-color: #E65E5E;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
  width: 50%;
}

.slide {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: scale(0.9) translateY(30px);
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
  bottom: 7px;
  transform: scale(0.95) translateY(15px);
  opacity: 0.75;
  z-index: 2
}

.slide:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 14px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.next:hover {
  color: #E65E5E;
}

.prev:hover {
  color: #E65E5E;
}

.prev {
  left: 160px;
}

.next {
  right: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide one"></div>
  <div class="slide two"></div>
  <div class="slide three"></div>
</div>

<div class="next">Next</div>
<div class="prev">Prev</div>
```

При клике на "Next" слайды меняются местами (анимация z-оси).

1 - 3, 2 - 1, 3 - 2.

Сделал стилизацию классов `:nth-child(n)`. Нужно создать массив элементов `.slide` с переписью со старой выборки массива. И так каждый раз при клике на `Next`, и наоборот при `Prev`.

Есть получше идеи как сделать такой слайдер с плавными переходами по оси z? Спасибо.

Comment: Что-то не видно кода вашего решения. Этот ресурс не поможет написать решение за вас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо именно самостоятельное решение данной задачи? Вы можете воспользоваться готовыми решениями вроде slick (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) или swiper (http://idangero.us/swiper/). Быстро подключаются и довольно просто стилизуются.